# Getting AppDelegate reference while creating framework swift

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

I am creating a custom framework. I need a reference to the AppDelegate to perform operations e.g get window or some other delegates.

example code:

```
static var safeArea: UIEdgeInsets {
    var padding: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        if let b = appDel.window?.safeAreaInsets {
            padding = b
        }
    }
    return padding
}
```

The main issue I have is that I need the AppDelegate reference on multiple levels.

Any help regarding this should be appreciated.

Comment: `UIApplication.shared.delegate`? Note that it might be in `SceneDelegate`?

Comment: @ElTomato you have sufficient rep to edit questions. Why not help people rather than posting snarky comments

Comment: while creating framework there is no class of appdelegate

Comment: @Paulw11 If I correct every typo, that would be my day job.  I do have a day job.

Comment: Ok, but pointing out spelling and grammatical errors isn't particularly helpful or welcoming to people who may not speak English well.  In some cases questions are truly incomprehensible but you clearly understood the meaning in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample Source for comments below :). Create a sampleManager inside framework. Import the framework into appdelegate and set SampleManager.shared.delegate to self as weak reference.

```
public class SampleManager {

    public static let shared = SampleManager()
    
    public weak var delegate: UIApplicationDelegate?
    
    func doWhateverYouWant() {
    
    }
}
```

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    private let dependencyManager = DependencyManager()

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        
        SampleManager.shared.delegate = self
        
        startAppCoordinator()
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: the main issue is i dont have class of appDelegate. as when you create a new project as framework it does not contain files like appdelegate/ Assets etc

Comment: All right. So why don't you develop a manager which has an init method required appDelegate reference while application initialize. Your framework would have a manager class which is responsible to create safeArea properties. In appDelegate while application is launching you can inject your framework manager into that method and give appdelegate reference inside to it. Then you can use that appdelegate reference inside of your manager to calculate properties values.

Comment: can you share some code snippet with above implementation?remeber one thing its not matter of getting safe area only i need other operations of appdelegate to be performed as well.

Comment: I edited my answer @HAMZAZULFQAR :). SampleManager inside framework now is capable of reaching out UIApplicationDelegate methods. Have fun :)

Comment: Got Your point hopefully it will work ThankYou 

Comment: Have fun mate :)