# Swift Use Custom Variables of AppDelegate in Framework

Tags: swift, xcode, object, frameworks, appdelegate

I have an application which contains some framework.
AppDelegate declares some variables, so I want to use these custom variables in framework. but unfortunately not getting it.
I use this stack overflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68191651/3485420) according to this answer I am able to use app delegate methods like didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and other methods but not able to get the custom variables and methods from app delegate.

```
 public class SampleManager {


    public static let shared = SampleManager()

    public weak var delegate: UIApplicationDelegate?//UIApplicationDelegate?

    func doWhateverYouWant() {

    }
}
```

I declared the SampleManager and assign its delegate in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions like this

```
SampleManager.shared.delegate = self
```

now this delegate allow me to access default methods and variables like `window`
but not allowing me custom methods and variables.
Kindly guide me how to access custom variables and custom methods declared in app delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `UIApplicationDelegate` doesn't contain your custom ones, just extend it

```
protocol Custom: UIApplicationDelegate {
    func yourFunc()
}

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, Custom {
    func yourFunc() {}
    ...
}

class SampleManager {
    static let shared = SampleManager()
    weak var delegate: Custom?

    func doWhateverYouWant() {
        delegate?.yourFunc()
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much... This sudo code worked for me... I update it according to my requirements. Thanks.